# Python regex works online but not in code

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x

This regex pattern: `^.+\'(.+.png)` works in online editors but not in python code. I saw other posts having the same issue. I tried applying those;

- Adding an extra escape slash
- Prepending start quote with `r`

the regex should match starting at single quote untill it hits .png.

For example:

With this string `Executing identify -format %k 'testcases/art/test_files/video_images/single-[snk1=640x480p59.9]-[src1=720x480i59.9].png'`

I want: `testcases/art/test_files/video_images/single-[snk1=640x480p59.9]-[src1=720x480i59.9].png`

I tried (not in chronological order):

```py
result = re.findall("^.+\\'(.+\\.png)", self.stream.getvalue()) # I also tried prepending all of these with r
result = re.findall("^.+\'(.+.png)", self.stream.getvalue())
result = re.findall("^.+'(.+.png)", self.stream.getvalue())
result = re.findall("^.+'(.+.png)", str(self.stream.getvalue()))
result = re.findall("\^.+'(.+.png)\", self.stream.getvalue())
```

Edit: I also tried using `re.match()` and `re.search()`

Update:

Probably where I'm getting the string from is responsible `cStringIO.StringO.getvalue()` which is this part in code `self.stream.getvalue()`. This is code I have not written. How can I use regex on this?

Comment: Your second and third lines with `re.findall` work. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/1wQneq). Just mind you need to escape the `.` before `png` as it is a literal dot.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It appears where I'm getting the string from is responsible. I get the string from `cStringIO.StringO.getvalue()`

Comment: And what is the contents of `cStringIO.StringO.getvalue()`? What you posted is not what you have then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `self.stream` is the `cStringIO.StringO` object. `self.stream.getvalue()` is `cStringIO.StringO.getvalue()` ? The content is the example string (plus more) I described

Comment: Usually, something like `re.findall("'([^']+\.png)'", str(self.stream.getvalue()))` might work

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Worked like a charm! Make an answer out of it if you want.

Comment: as a general recommendation.

prefix the strings containing the regular expressions with an r (raw string), then you should be able to use the same regexp, that you tested online. raw string have implicit escaping for backslashes enabled, and you will not be lost in a sea of multiple backslashes

Comment: @gelonida Uhmm, have you read the whole post? Because I stated I tried doing that as well :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the output of `self.stream.getvalue()` to a string and also throw away the `^.+` part of the pattern as `re.findall` searches for all matches anywhere inside the input string.

Use

```
results = re.findall(r"'([^']+\.png)", str(self.stream.getvalue()))
```

Also, mind escaping dots that are literal `.` chars in the pattern.

**Pattern details**

- `'` -  a single quote
- `([^']+\.png)`  - Capturing group 1:

  - `[^']+` - 1+ chars other than `'`
  - `\.png` - `.png` substring.

Comment: I actually do need all occurences of .png files. is `re.findall( "'([^']+\.png)'", str(self.stream.getvalue()))` still going to work always, if it is between single quotes?

Comment: @BasVelden I edited the answer and added the pattern explanation. I assume there is only one match inside single quotes.